# How to send a notification with a category using Firebase

Tags: ios, json, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm implementing an interactive remote notification in iOS. I'm sending notifications via Firebase. The notification should contain a "category" identifier to be associated with a concrete action. An example from a tutorial:

{    aps : { 
        alert : "notificationText",
        category: "myCategory"
   } 
}

But how to use this JSON and assign a category for a notification in Firebase?

Comment: The answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137727/how-to-send-actionable-notifications-to-ios-with-firebase).

Answer (score -2):

[image]

you can add your custom data with key value pair from the advance options tab