# iOS Push Notification Action is not showing up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app has a connection to the Firebase-server, also to send Push Notifications. Now, I want to go a step further and add an action to the notifications. After going throw lots of tutorials, it´s still not working for me. The action-button is not showing up, as you can see here:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    registerForPushNotifications()
    return true
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
        (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

        guard granted else { return }

        let viewAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "addToCal",
                                              title: "Zum Kalender hinzufügen",
                                              options: [.foreground])

        let newsCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "NEW_SESSION",
                                                  actions: [viewAction],
                                                  intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                  options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([newsCategory])
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}

func getNotificationSettings() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
        print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
}
```

As I saw at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial, I also added the "category" key with the value "NEW_SESSION" to the push notification I´m sending, but it´s not working as well.[image]

**Update:**
I noticed that the "category" key is passed through the notification, so its just a question to handle it right. The userInfo Dictionary looks like this:

```
{ "aps" : { 
"alert" : { 
"body" : "This notification has no action", 
"title" : "Test", 
} 
}, 
"category" : "NEW_SESSION" 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure. From your viewAction: try changing **from**  `[.foreground]` to  `[]`

Comment: Nope, nothing has changed:( Thanks for your answer dude:)

Comment: FYI when you receive the notification, it will look the same. To see the actions you must  **tap** and **drag** the notification down. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can see it in the picture above:D

Comment: I did see the image. Not sure if I communicated well. After seeing the notification on your screen: Did you tap and drag the notification down?!

Comment: Yes of course :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148940/discussion-between-honey-and-devhess).

Comment: @Honey, Now I implemented a function that displays the userInfo in an alertView. It looks like [this](http://imgur.com/xIILjRx). It should also display the category String I set, shouldn't´t? But it´s not doing.

Comment: Delete the app.( dont reinstall. Delete it and then install again) and see if it works. If that doesn't work then also do a clean build using cmmd k and also do cmmd + shift + k. But I have a reason to believe deleting it and installing it again could solve your problem

Comment: My point is make sure after you delete and install the app...the app  shows you the alert of "allow notifications" / "dont allow notifications".

Comment: Also in case you haven't noticed you misspelled category. You wrote it as 'catogary'

Comment: @Honey, Jup the alert to allow/not allow was poping up. And no, nothing has changed:( At the [firebase doc] (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) I noticed that you have to use "click_action" instead of "category". But this hasn't changed anything, and that's why I've contacted the firebase support now. Thank you for your support:)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137727/how-to-send-actionable-notifications-to-ios-with-firebase) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297505/firebase-cloud-messaging-click-action-format-is-platform-specific). You have to accomplish that through an API call.

Comment: @Honey, I don´t understand where I have to type in the HTTP messages:/

Comment: I don't know where you have to write that request. Ask that on the linked answers.

Answer (score 8):

The buttons do not appear on their own. On supported devices you have to 3D touch the notifications to show the content or buttons. On non-supported devices you can try swiping down or left/right for the buttons to show.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

            guard granted else { return }

            let action = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "addToCal", title: "Zum Kalender hinzufügen", options: [])
            let category = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "NEW_SESSION", actions: [action], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([category])

            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
```

And add `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` methods to handle action.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // Print message ID.
        // Print full message.
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        if response.actionIdentifier == "addToCal" {

            //Handel action.
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forgot to set delegate as:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Payload format

```
{
    "aps" : {
              "category" : "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY",
               "alert" : {
                        "body" : "Acme message received from Johnny Appleseed",
                        "title" : "Test",
                    },
               "badge" : 3,
             },
}
```

Comment: In the tutorial i links above, the payload looks like this: `{
  "aps": {
    "alert": "Breaking News!",
    "sound": "default",
    "link_url": "https://raywenderlich.com",
    "category": "NEWS_CATEGORY"
  }
}`  and mine is `{ "aps" : { 
"alert" : { 
"body" : "This notification has no action", 
"title" : "Test", 
} 
}, 
"catogary" : "NEW_SESSION" 
}`. As you can see, in the working payload "category" is placed in "aps" and mine not. I'm pretty sure that the error/bug is caused by this.

Comment: @Devhess Please match the payload format as my updated answer
or you can follow https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

Comment: @NikhleshBagdiya I cannot change the order in the payload. I've contacted the firebase support now.

Comment: @Devhess for actionable firebase notification you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39137727/how-to-send-actionable-notifications-to-ios-with-firebase

Comment: The fact that the buttons don't show up automatically unless the user performs a 3D touch on the notification was an important piece of information that I was missing!  Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 2):

For me it works when I have the "category" included in "aps" dictionary and it does not work when I have it outside of "aps". And also, did you guys noticed that in the payload that Devhess posted as an update to his question the **"category" field is misspelled**. So instead of "category" we have "catogary" there. This also could be the problem.
This payload works for me:

`{
   "aps":{
      "alert":{
         "body":"This notification has ACTIONS",
         "title":"ACTIONABLE Notification title"
      },
      "badge":1,
      "sound":"default",
      "category":"NEW_SESSION"
   }
}`